# Value of an element array changing inside

Tags: php, arrays, pass-by-reference

I have a PHP application that has the following code:

```
    $cod = 0;
    $array = array();
    $myObj = new MyClass();
    for($i = 0; $i < 10; $i++){

        $myObj->setCod($cod);

        array_push($array, $myObj);

        $cod++;
    }

    print_r($array);
```

All the objects in the array are with the property COD with the value 9, like this:

```
Array
(
    [0] => MyClass Object
        (
            [Cod:MyClass:private] => 9
        )
    ...
    [0] => MyClass Object
        (
            [Cod:MyClass:private] => 9
        )

)
```

And what I want is a sequential number in Cod property. I don't know what is happening, something is passed by reference?

I cant use the $i variable in this case.

Comment: What does your `setCod` method look like?

Comment: in newer PHP versions, objects are passed by reference, so you're effectively pushing the SAME object into your array multiple times. you'd have to instantiate a new object, or clone it, each time you do a push.

Comment: @MarcB yeah, it worked now, thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'd need

```
for(...) {
    $temp = new MyClass();
    $temp->setCod($i);
    $array[] = $temp;
}
```

which creates a new independent object on every iteration. Otherwise you're pushing references to the SAME object each time, which then makes for the same "cod" value internally, because it's all the SAME thing internally.